# Can run simple Script with PowerShell, but task scheduler doesn't?

Tags: powershell

I created a simple PowerShell script to copy items from a remote location to my google drive, the script runs using the option run with PowerShell.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\myipaddress\Exports" -Recurse -Filter F7104016E30A0465* | 
  Copy-Item -Destination "G:\My Drive\storage" -Force
```

However I am trying to automate the script with task scheduler to run it daily and it is not copy the file into the destination folder. the task does not show an error.

in action tab I select start program and add argument: `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\test\script.ps1`, there is not error on the log but it doesn't show incremental (1 file) in the google drive.

Comment: I've done it for this post, but in the future please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Is `G:` a _mapped_ drive, or a local drive? If it is mapped, that mapping may not be available in the context of the scheduled task.

Comment: G: is the drive that google drive desktop app added, so yeah it is a mapped drive

Comment: Then the user running the scheduled task is not you and therefore this mapping isn't valid..